# React Router Navbar background change only works in pages folder, but not on App.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-rhodes-ffcmc?file=/src/components/Navbar.js:792-856

Right now it just changes the routes, but the nav background color stays the same.

So, I have this navbar component that changes the color of the background based on a specific page I am located on. It works fine if I add the navbar individually to each page. However, I end up repeating a ton of code.

So here is my original setup

```
--pages
   Home.js
   About.js
   Contact.js
```

And here is my function to toggle the mobile menu open and closed on the Home page

```
  const Home = () => {
        const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

        const toggle = () => {
          setIsOpen(!isOpen);
        };

        return (
          <>
            <Dropdown isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
            <Navbar toggle={toggle} />
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
          </>
        );
      };

      export default Home;
```

Now my issue is that this is hard coded into my Home.js file, so if I want my navbar and dropdown to work on any other page, I would have to copy and paste the exact same components + function to open/close the mobile menu.

If I try adding it on the App.js, so it displays on every single page, then that is when my issue occurs and the function I have to change the navbar background stops working

```
      function App() {
        const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

        const toggle = () => {
          setIsOpen(!isOpen);
        };

        return (
          <>
            <Dropdown isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
            <Navbar toggle={toggle} />
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
              <Route path='/about' component={About} />
              <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
            </Switch>
          </>
        );
      }

      export default App;
```

Here is my function that changes the navbar based on window location pathname in my Navbar.js

```
      const Navbar = ({ toggle }) => {
        const [navbar, setNavbar] = useState(false);

        useEffect(() => {
          if (window.location.pathname) {
            setNavbar(window.location.pathname);
          }

          console.log(window.location.pathname);
        }, []);
```

So why does my navbar change background colors fine when I manually hard code the navbar in each page, but when I try to add it to my App.js it stops working?

It looks like my function to get the `window.location.pathname` stops working whenever I add my Navbar to the `App.js` file, but if I manually add my navbar into my pages/Home.js file it works completely fine. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was working because `<Navbar />` component was mounted/unmounted each time when the navigation happened, hance the `useEffect` with empty dependencies array was being called.

Since you moved your `<Navbar />` into an upper-level component (which you should actually do) your `useEffect` is being called only once.
Make sure to `import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom`

To fix the issue do this:

```
    const location = useLocation();
    useEffect(() => {
      if (location.pathname) {
        setNavbar(location.pathname);
      }

      console.log(location.pathname);
    }, [location.pathname]);
```

You can also use `useLocation` hook instead of `window.location` to get access to the `pathname`.
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation

Here is the working codesandbox example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-architecture-d76pl?file=/src/components/Navbar.js

Comment: that still doesn't update my navbar bg color based on pathname. It just gives me this error `React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'window.location.pathname'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values like 'window.location.pathname' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component `

Comment: I've updated my code so you can more easily reuse it. It uses the `useLocation` which I originally mentioned as a preferred way. Also, look at the link I've provided to familiarize yourself further.

Comment: but I have to downgrade to react 16.8 How else can I get the location without downgrading my react version?

Comment: Why would you have to downgrade?
Which `react-router-dom` version do you have specified in your `package.json`?

Comment: I have the latest react version, yet I still get that error for some reason. `    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",`

Do you know why that happens?

Comment: also, I added a codesandbox, so maybe you can see what the issue is

Comment: Works perfectly fine. You're probably importing the `useLocation` wrong.
Here is the working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-architecture-d76pl?file=/src/components/Navbar.js

Comment: ah finally it works. I guess I didn't import it in the proper spot which is why it kept giving me the error

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in useEffect which will invoke only on mount for the firs time and there is a hook called `useLocation` which will rerender your component when location change.

here the final code:

```
const NavBar =()=>{
    const {pathname}= useLocation()
    
    return <div style={{backgroundColor:pathname==="/"?"red":"white"}}>navbar</div>
}
```